# C# EventViewer Count EventID's

Tags: c#, count, event-viewer

Going Nuts!!!!

I need a loop that will count the entries in the eventViewer based on EVENTID. I can count the total entries in the eventViewer using this code:

```
    foreach (System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntry entry in myEventLog.Entries)
    {
        int myEventEntry = myLogEntryCollection.Count;
        Console.WriteLine(myEventEntry);
        Console.Read();
    }
```

But i cant yet count all entries with eventID = 17137 for example (SQL Event). PLEASE HELP!!

B

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
string query = "*[System/EventID=17137 ]";
EventLogQuery eventsQuery = new EventLogQuery("Application", PathType.LogName, query);

try
    {
    EventLogReader logReader = new EventLogReader(eventsQuery);

    for (EventRecord eventdetail = logReader.ReadEvent(); eventdetail != null; eventdetail = logReader.ReadEvent())
    {
        // Read Event details
    }
}
catch (EventLogNotFoundException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error while reading the event logs");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Neel....appreciated. But i just solved myself. Create a variable called numberofEvents and in the loop i just ++numberOfEvents. Not the cleanest but i will save me from getting fired for another week lol!!

Comment: hehe okk all the best @macca